# javascript var LZstring in POST format

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have noticed, that Ajax is not capable of sending var created from LZString. If I put Base64 it sends it without problems. How can I solve this?

```
function compress(a) {
    var compressed = LZString.compress(a);

    var e = document.getElementById("usuario");
    var User = e.value;
    var u = document.getElementById("texto");
    var text = u.value;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "upload-documento.php",
        ataType: "json",
        data: { "usuario": User, "doc": compressed, "texto": text },
        beforeSend: function () {
            toastr.info("En proceso! Si tarda mas de 30 segundos porfavor reinicia la App!", "Operación en proceso");
        },
        success: function () {
            toastr.success("Archivo creado con exito exito!", "Con exito");
        },
        error: function () {
            toastr.error("Algo a salido Mal!", "ERROR");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: In the [documentation](https://pieroxy.net/blog/pages/lz-string/index.html) it is said, that "_lib produces stuff that isn't really a string_", but there seems to be a a method for URLs, `compressToEncodedURIComponent`.

Comment: but this way, it weighs more than base64